# Conversão de String em time.Time

Tags: data, golang

Boa tarde!
Queria saber como faço para converte/transformar uma String data no formato (dd/mm/yyyy) em time.Time

Answer (score 0):

Existe a função [`Parse`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Parse) para esta finalidade (converter um valor de data humano para o time.Time).

É importante que você esteja familiarizado com o formato usado, isso pode ser [visualizado aqui](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#pkg-constants).

---

O formato de `dd/mm/yyyy` é equivalente à `02/01/2006`, conforme mencionado acima. O `time.Parse` requer dois valores: o formato e a data. Então basta utilizar:

```
formato := `02/01/2006` // Este é o DD/MM/YYYY
data := `18/03/2020`    // Este é a data que quer converter para time.Time

t, err := time.Parse(formato, data)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal("A data inserida é inválida") 
}
```

---

Se quiser que o formato seja: `d/m/yyyy`. Sendo mais claro, se quiser aceitar uma data como: 1/1/2000 (ao invés de somente aceitar 01/01/2000), você deve usar o `2/1/2006` como formato (ao invés do `02/01/2006`).

Enfim: se for obrigado à usar `0` (como **0**1/**0**1/2000) use `02/01/2006`, se não use `2/1/2006`.

Comment: muito Obrigado!